# ngAngular-js Hide parent element if child element is empty

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use angular to show/hide or remove a parent div, dependant on the contents of a child div.

```
<div id="display-wrapper">
  <div class="display-title">{{SELECTION.TITLE}}</div>
  <div class="display-text">{{selection.text|| SELECTION.NO_TEXT}}</div>
</div>
```

Depending on what the user has selected in a search window the div will be populated with data.  Sometimes there will be no data for these particular divs. 
I am happy to use ngShow or ngIf as it won't affect display or logic.
So if the child div display-text is empty, I want the parent div to be removed or hidden.

I have tried capturing innerHTML or innerText and while I can do it for the parent div, I cannot get the parent div to operate based on the contents of the child.

**Addition after suggestion.**

Is it possible my site is interfering?
If I try the following on jsfiddle it behaves as I want.

```
<div id="display-wrapper" ng-show='{{selection.text}}'>
  <div class="display-title">{{SELECTION.TITLE}}</div>
  <div class="display-text">{{selection.text|| SELECTION.NO_TEXT}}</div>
</div>
```

essentially if there is a value assigned to selection.text the div shows, if either selection.text is not assigned or is assigned the empty string, the div does not show.

When I try this on the site I get the following code generated.

(1) When selection.text = "I should be visible"

```
<div id="display-wrapper" ng-show="I should be visible" style="display: none;">
  <div class="display-title ng-binding">
    TITLE
  </div>
  <div class="display-text" ng-binding">
    I should be visible
  </div>
</div>
```

(2) When selection.text = ""

```
<div id="display-wrapper" ng-show="" style="display: none;">
  <div class="display-title ng-binding">
    TITLE
  </div>
  <div class="display-text" ng-binding">
    no user data
  </div>
</div>
```

(2) is doing what it should do and not displaying, (1) should display as  ng-show="I should be visible" but the code has generated a style="display: none;"

Any help please?

Comment: `ng-show='{{selection.text||SELECTION.NO_TEXT||SELECTION.TITLE}}'` does not work? (if this gets too complex, move the condition to the controller `ng-show='sectionIsEmpty()'` or model `ng-show='sectionIsEmpty'`)

Comment: we can ignore SELECTION.TITLE
I tried variations on ng-show='{{selection.text||SELECTION.NO_TEXT}', no joy.  SELECTION.NO_TEXT populates the empty div with "no user data".  when I use the above I get ng-show="WHATEVER THE USER HAS ADDED" or ng-show="no user data" and the div is visible.
If I modify it to ng-show='{{selection.text||""}' I get ng-show="WHATEVER THE USER HAS ADDED" or ng-show="" and in both cases I get style="display:none" being added to the div and in all cases the div is not-visible.

Comment: oops. Probably `ng-show='selection.text||SELECTION.NO_TEXT'` (without the braces).

Comment: Thilo, that worked.  In my defence I have been using angularjs for just under a week.  If you want to post it as an answer I can mark it right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="display-wrapper" ng-show='{{selection.text}}'>
```

This looks like it results in double interpolation. The `{{ }}` is for interpolating an expression into HTML, it is not necessary when we are already in a place where Angular expects an expression.

You should change it to

```
<div id="display-wrapper" ng-show='selection.text'>
```

You say the first pattern still works on JSFiddle. No idea why. Maybe a different version of Angular? Either way, the second pattern should work for all situations.

Comment: I am not sure why I got a jsfiddle success there, possibly as I included the values as $scope variables?  I am not to concerned as your explanation makes sense and solved my problem, thanks.